# Trying to add a string value to a SQL database - help and advice

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a string value to a SQL database in SQL Server Managemnet Studio but this does not work.

What is the correct way to do this?

```
SqlCommand addProduct = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES(" + txtProductName.Text + ");", sqlConnect);
try
{
   addProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
   MessageBox.Show("This product has been succesfully added to the database!!");

}
catch (Exception error2)
{
   MessageBox.Show(error2.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to include a quote for the added string. Something like this

```
SqlCommand addProduct = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES('" + txtProductName.Text + "');", sqlConnect);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider what is being generated here:

```cs
addProduct = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES(" + txtProductName.Text + ");", sqlConnect);
```

If the value of txtProductName.Text is "`monkey nuts`", then your SqlCommand will have a CommandText of:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES(monkey nuts);
```

This isn't valid SQL, as the string has not been quoted. Now, if the value of txtProductName.Text is "`'foo');DROP TABLE Test; --`", then your SqlCommand will have a CommandText of:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES('foo');DROP TABLE Test; --);
```

Which, whilst valid SQL (as I'd put the apostrophes in the text box to quote the string), isn't what you'd want to do either.

The safest approach is to use parametrisation, so something more like:

```cs
using (SqlCommand addProduct = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES(@ProductName);", sqlConnect);
{
   addProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtProductName.Text;

   addProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
   MessageBox.Show("This product has been succesfully added to the database!!");
}
```